# Windows Phone : Where and How App instance is injected in MainPage

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In `MainPage.xaml.cs`, I see

```
DataContext = App.ViewModel;
```

When I go up the inheritance tree, I can't find `App` anywhere. So where and how is `App` injected ?

**Update:** My question is not about `ViewModel`. It's about `App`. How `App` is accessible to `MainPage`. `App` is not injected into `MainPage` from `MainPage`'s constructor so how is this possible ?

Comment: App is the initial class where you launch everything from app.xaml.cs. I believe the reason why app is available is that your page via Navigationserivce adds page to the rootfram (also available in app)? Just a guess :)

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>F12</kbd> on `App` and Visual Studio will show the class definition. The corresponding files are located in the project root. `App.ViewModel` is a static member of the `App` class, so it's available throughout the project without having an instance of the `App` class. If you need an instance, use `Application.Current`.

Comment: My question is not about ViewModel. It's about App. How App is accessible to MainPage ? App is not injected into MainPage from MainPage's Constructor so how is this possible ?

Comment: In your code example App is a class, not an instance. You can always access any class from MainPage (or from any other class) - simply because that's how C# works.